# How do I know that my CPU supports 64bit operating systems under Linux?

Tags: linux, 64bit, x86

How can I find out that my CPU supports 64bit operating systems under Linux, e.g.: Ubuntu, Fedora?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How come I installed Ubuntu 64 bit on a Pentium 4 machine?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/how-come-i-installed-ubuntu-64-bit-on-a-pentium-4-machine)

Comment: More generally, see [What do the flags in /proc/cpuinfo mean?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43539)

Comment: Once you have checked the flags, then install the kernel package. Debian and Ubuntu, can run a 64bit kernel with a 32 bit userland. Installing the kernel is quick. Do not remove the old 32bit one, as you may need to go back to it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Execute:

`grep flags /proc/cpuinfo`

Find 'lm' flag. If it's present, it means your CPU is 64bit and it supports 64bit OS. 'lm' stands for long mode.

Alternatively, execute:

`grep flags /proc/cpuinfo | grep " lm "`

Note the spaces in `" lm "`. If it gives any output at all, your CPU is 64bit.

Update: You can use the following in terminal too:

`lshw -C processor | grep width`

This works on Ubuntu, not sure if you need to install additional packages for Fedora.

Comment: Afaik it won't work if "lm" is the last flag in the line. :-)

Answer (score 33):

I think the easiest way is by:

```
lscpu|grep "CPU op-mode"
```

Comment: This answer is the best. It shows you an explicit "32-bit" or "64-bit". I don't see why people choose the other answer over this one. You don't even need to grep anything. Just doing `lscpu` is so simple. If they don't have the `lscpu` command then I could see why they voted for the other one.

Comment: The command that is the most portable across the largest variety of platforms is arguably the most useful.

Comment: I got '32-bit, 64-bit' What does it mean?

Comment: It is a 64-bit machine running in 32-bit mode.

Answer (score 2):

If your CPU is a 64bit one (x86-64), you can use it with a 64 bit OS.

Here is a list of 64bit CPUs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#Current_64-bit_microprocessor_architectures

Comment: This is the ultra slow way, and not guaranteed to give you an answer.

Comment: @trusktr:  Yes. but all the other ways require Linux to be installed already.  Not much help if you have an old Win32 machine and want to know if it will run a 64 bit *nix OS

Comment: Same here. Found this useful, not having a running OS on the system in question to test it with.

Answer (score 2):

via this command `dmidecode -t processor` we can check the processor capability.

Comment: That outputs a ton of other stuff, and splits "64-bit capable" on a different line than it's vague heading ("Characteristics"), so it's difficult to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on the high scoring answers to this question because these methods are not always correct.

I've a computer with a Intel Atom N230 CPU which according to all of the tests mentioned is capable to support 64 bit OS'es.

According to `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Atom#32-bit_and_64-bit_hardware_support` the CPU is not capable of running 64 bit OS'es.
I've tried to install a 64 bit Linux OS and it indeed refuses to do so. Installing a 32 bit Linux OS works.