# How can I determine if my processor is 64 or 32 bit?

Tags: debian, 64bit, 32bit, x86

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I know that my CPU supports 64bit operating systems under Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14384/how-do-i-know-that-my-cpu-supports-64bit-operating-systems-under-linux)

I am running Debian Squeeze, how can I determine whether my processor is 64 or 32-bit? I'm thinking of downloading a 64-bit OS because it's said to perform better.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Type `grep lm /proc/cpuinfo` (lm stands for [**l**ong **m**ode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_mode))

Or just try booting with a 64-bit OS: if you do not have 64-bit support, it will say so and not boot.

```
lm: Long Mode (x86-64: amd64, also known as Intel 64, i.e. 64-bit capable)
```

Comment: look what happen when i've used this comand

Comment: The `lm` flag is there, that means your system supports 64-bit.

Comment: it's not true i tried uname -m and it show me i686 exactly as @cjc said

Comment: `uname -m` refers to the architecture of the **currently running kernel**, if you'rre running a 32-bits kernel it will show `i686` even if you CPU supports 64-bit.

Comment: so it means my computer suport 64 bits, thanks for the answer

Comment: @Zignd `uname -m` can even show `i686` to a process on an x86_64 processor running an x86_64 kernel, if the process (or an ancestor) called `setpersonality`.

Comment: @Gilles I didn't know about `setpersonality`. Very interesting

Comment: Try `uname -p` (as in `--processor`) per this Linux [*man page*](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uname) I stumbled upon with Google. Another fun diversion is `uname -a` and then try to remember which options correspond to which returned values. ;-)