# 64-bit kernel, but all 32-bit ELF executable running processes, how is this?

Tags: linux, 64bit, 32bit, cpu-architecture

The output from `uname`:

```
root@debian:~ # uname -a
Linux 5asnb 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Mon Jun 13 05:49:32 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

However the `/sbin/init` executable shows up as 32-bit:

```
root@debian:~ # file /sbin/init
/sbin/init: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped
```

Other aspects of the system seem to contradict things as well:

```
root@debian:~ # echo $HOSTTYPE
i486

root@debian:~ # getconf LONG_BIT
32
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 64bit kernel can be installed on Debian 32bit. You can see that the amd64 kernel is available for 32bit Debian on it's [package page](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/linux-image-amd64). This can be used as an alternative to using a PAE enabled kernel to support more than 4G of total RAM. Note that 32bit binaries still can not access more than roughly 3G of RAM per process.

Comment: thx! your answers is as clear as a crystal ball~ :D
Never noticed Debian treat kernel package like this way before.

Comment: That's not true: 32 bit programs can use the whole 4Gio of their virtual address space when running on a 64-bit kernel (unless they are running with the ADDR_LIMIT_3GB personality).

Comment: @ysdx So limiting to 2GB is a Windows specific thing and addresses above 0x80000000 will be allowed in 32-bit userspace?

Comment: @PaulStelian, On 32 bit Windows, you are by default limited to the lowest 2GB of virtual memory for retro-compatibility (I think some programs used to reserve pointers to the highest 2GB of virtual memory for special purpose). You can set the LARGEADDRESSAWARE flag in your executable (https://docs.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/build/reference/largeaddressaware-handle-large-addresses?view=vs-2019) to opt-in getting access to the whole 4GB of virtual memory.

Answer (score 14):

All processors that support the [x64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X64) instruction set (also known as x86_64 or amd64) also support the [x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) instruction set (also known as i386 or i686, which are strictly speaking specific versions of x86). The same goes for [ARM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) A64 (the new 64-bit instruction set appearing in ARMv8) and A32 (the name for the “classic” 32-bit instruction set), for [SPARC64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARC64) and [SPARC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARC), and I believe for [MIPS64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS64#MIPS64) and [MIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_instruction_set). So on all these architecture families, if a processor can run 64-bit code, it can also run 32-bit code.

The Linux kernel supports running 32-bit userland code with a 64-bit kernel (on all the architecture families mentioned above, I think). The kernel must be homogeneous (all 64-bit or all 32-bit), and each process must be homogeneous, but you can have a mixture of 32-bit and 64-bit processes on a 64-bit kernel. The converse is not possible: with a 32-bit kernel, you cannot run 64-bit processes.

This is a design choice in Linux, motivated by the desire to run existing 32-bit binaries on 64-bit installations. Other Unix variants have made different choices: Solaris can run 64-bit programs on a 32-bit kernel as well as the other way round, while OpenBSD cannot run 32-bit programs on a 64-bit kernel.

You can get [information about the CPU](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38415/how-can-i-determine-if-my-processor-is-64-or-32-bit) in `/proc/cpuinfo`. If your x86 CPU has the `lm` flag, it's a 64-bit CPU.

By default, `uname -m` or `arch` shows the architecture that the kernel was compiled for. Linux can set the “personality” of a process (with the [`personality`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/personality.2.html)) system call. You can run a subprocess in a different personality with the [`setarch`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setarch.8.html) command; `setarch i686 someprogram` or `linux32 someprogram` runs the specified program in an environment where `uname -m` returns `i686` while `setarch amd64 someprogram` or `linux64 someprogram` runs the specified program in an environment where `uname -m` returns `amd64`.

`file /sbin/init` tells you what architecture the `init` program is compiled for. Although it's possible to mix 32-bit and 64-bit executables in an installation, usually all the core OS programs are from the same architecture, because it's a lot easier to manage.

`$HOSTYPE` is a bash variable and tells you what architecture the `bash` program was compiled for.

`getconf LONG_BIT` lets you know whether the default C compiler is set up to compile 32-bit or 64-bit programs. A more precise test is to compile a and run a program that prints `sizeof(void*)` or `sizeof(size_t)` — calling `getconf` can only give information about what `getconf` thinks is the default compiler.

Comment: Indeed, does 32 bit Solaris switch to 64 bit mode to switch to 64-bit process and then back? This must have a huge overhead, and just makes no sense, because then the kernel is effectively 64 bit.

Comment: @Ruslan Why would it have a huge overhead? Switching modes on a context switch doesn't cost much (if anything, I don't know x86 at a low level well enough). The kernel remains 32-bit: 32-bit virtual addresses for kernel mappings, use of 32-bit the instruction set.

Comment: The kernel must maintain some 64-bit-specific data structures to support 64 bit apps, at least 64bit-aware page tables. This makes it not really a 32 bit kernel. I've not tried to get really deep into amd64 arch, but I think switching 64 bit support off will have considerable overhead in contrast to using specially designed compatibility mode.

Comment: @Ruslan Only 64-bit aware page tables and really necessary, and it's a tiny cost. Everything else can be avoided with the right kernel design. I've never dug into the Solaris kernel, I presume they arranged to make it flexible enough (they had prior experience with SPARC64).