# What do the flags in /proc/cpuinfo mean?

Tags: linux, cpu, arm, x86

How can I tell whether my processor has a particular feature? (64-bit instruction set, hardware-assisted virtualization, cryptographic accelerators, etc.) I know that the file `/proc/cpuinfo` contains this information, in the `flags` line, but what do all these cryptic abbreviations mean?

For example, given the following extract from `/proc/cpuinfo`, do I have a 64-bit CPU? Do I have hardware virtualization?

```
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E8400  @ 3.00GHz
…
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 lahf_lm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority
```

Comment: I find [this csv](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/arch/x86/kcpuid/cpuid.csv) explains a little more clear than cpufeatures.h. so I post it here as well.

Answer (score 357):

## x86

(32-bit a.k.a. i386–i686 and 64-bit a.k.a. amd64. In other words, your workstation, laptop or server.)

### FAQ: **Do I have…**

- 64-bit (x86_64/AMD64/Intel64)? **`lm`**
- Hardware virtualization (VMX/AMD-V)? **`vmx`** (Intel), **`svm`** (AMD)
- Accelerated AES (AES-NI)? **`aes`**
- TXT (TPM)? **`smx`**
- a hypervisor (announced as such)? **`hypervisor`**

Most of the other features are only of interest to compiler or kernel authors.

### All the flags

The full listing is in the kernel source, in the file [`arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeatures.h`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeatures.h).

#### Intel-defined CPU features, CPUID level 0x00000001 (edx)

*See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX.3D1:_Processor_Info_and_Feature_Bits) and table 2-27 in [Intel Advanced Vector Extensions Programming Reference](http://software.intel.com/file/36945)*

- `fpu`: Onboard [FPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit) (floating point support)
- `vme`: [Virtual 8086 mode enhancements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_8086_mode#Virtual_8086_mode_enhancements_.28VME.29)
- `de`: Debugging Extensions ([CR4.DE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_register#CR4))
- `pse`: [Page Size Extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_Size_Extension) (4MB [memory pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)))
- `tsc`: [Time Stamp Counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) (RDTSC)
- `msr`: [Model-Specific Registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-specific_register) (RDMSR, WRMSR)
- `pae`: [Physical Address Extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) (support for more than 4GB of RAM)
- `mce`: [Machine Check Exception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_Check_Exception)
- `cx8`: [CMPXCHG8 instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CMPXCHG8B:CMPXCHG16B.html) (64-bit [compare-and-swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare_and_swap))
- `apic`: Onboard [APIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programmable_Interrupt_Controller)
- `sep`: [SYSENTER](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SYSENTER.html)/[SYSEXIT](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SYSEXIT.html)
- `mtrr`: [Memory Type Range Registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_Type_Range_Registers)
- `pge`: [Page Global Enable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer#Address_space_switch) (global bit in PDEs and PTEs)
- `mca`: [Machine Check Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_check_architecture)
- `cmov`: [CMOV instructions](http://www.rcollins.org/p6/opcodes/CMOV.html) (conditional move) (also [FCMOV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FCMOV))
- `pat`: [Page Attribute Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_Attribute_Table)
- `pse36`: [36-bit PSEs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSE-36) (huge pages)
- `pn`: [Processor serial number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX.3D3:_Processor_Serial_Number)
- `clflush`: [Cache Line Flush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#CACHE-LINES) instruction
- `dts`: Debug Store (buffer for debugging and profiling instructions)
- `acpi`: [ACPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) via MSR (temperature monitoring and clock speed modulation)
- `mmx`: [Multimedia Extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMX_%28instruction_set%29)
- `fxsr`: FXSAVE/FXRSTOR, [CR4.OSFXSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_register#CR4)
- `sse`: Intel [SSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) vector instructions
- `sse2`: [SSE2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2)
- `ss`: CPU self [snoop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_snooping)
- `ht`: [Hyper-Threading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperthreading) and/or multi-core
- `tm`: Automatic clock control (Thermal Monitor)
- `ia64`: [Intel Itanium Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-64) 64-bit (not to be confused with Intel's 64-bit x86 architecture with flag `x86-64` or "AMD64" bit indicated by flag `lm`)
- `pbe`: [Pending Break Enable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX.3D1:_Processor_Info_and_Feature_Bits) (PBE# pin) wakeup support

#### AMD-defined CPU features, CPUID level 0x80000001

*See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX.3D80000001h:_Extended_Processor_Info_and_Feature_Bits) and table 2-23 in [Intel Advanced Vector Extensions Programming Reference](http://software.intel.com/file/36945)*

- `syscall`: [SYSCALL](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SYSCALL.html) (Fast System Call) and [SYSRET](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SYSRET.html) (Return From Fast System Call)
- `mp`: [Multiprocessing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessing) Capable.
- `nx`: [Execute Disable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit)
- `mmxext`: [AMD MMX extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMX_%28instruction_set%29)
- `fxsr_opt`: FXSAVE/FXRSTOR optimizations
- `pdpe1gb`: One GB [pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)) (allows `hugepagesz=1G`)
- `rdtscp`: [Read Time-Stamp Counter and Processor ID](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/RDTSCP.html)
- `lm`: [Long Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_mode) ([x86-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64): amd64, also known as Intel 64, i.e. 64-bit capable)
- `3dnowext`: AMD 3DNow! extensions
- `3dnow`: [3DNow!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3DNow%21) (AMD vector instructions, competing with Intel's SSE1)

#### Transmeta-defined CPU features, CPUID level 0x80860001

- `recovery`: CPU in recovery mode
- `longrun`: Longrun power control
- `lrti`: LongRun table interface

#### Other features, Linux-defined mapping

- `cxmmx`: Cyrix MMX extensions
- `k6_mtrr`: AMD K6 nonstandard MTRRs
- `cyrix_arr`: Cyrix ARRs (= MTRRs)
- `centaur_mcr`: Centaur MCRs (= MTRRs)
- `constant_tsc`: TSC ticks at a constant rate
- `up`: SMP kernel running on UP
- `art`: Always-Running Timer
- `arch_perfmon`: Intel Architectural PerfMon
- `pebs`: Precise-Event Based Sampling
- `bts`: Branch Trace Store
- `rep_good`: rep microcode works well
- `acc_power`: [AMD accumulated power mechanism](https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/1/6/873)
- `nopl`: The NOPL (0F 1F) instructions
- `xtopology`: cpu topology enum extensions
- `tsc_reliable`: [TSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) is known to be reliable
- `nonstop_tsc`: [TSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) does not stop in C states
- `cpuid`: CPU has CPUID instruction itself
- `extd_apicid`: has extended APICID (8 bits)
- `amd_dcm`: multi-node processor
- `aperfmperf`: APERFMPERF
- `eagerfpu`: Non lazy FPU restore
- `nonstop_tsc_s3`: [TSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) doesn't stop in S3 state
- `tsc_known_freq`: [TSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) has known frequency
- `mce_recovery`: CPU has recoverable machine checks

#### Intel-defined CPU features, CPUID level 0x00000001 (ecx)

*See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX.3D1:_Processor_Info_and_Feature_Bits) and table 2-26 in [Intel Advanced Vector Extensions Programming Reference](http://software.intel.com/file/36945)*

- `pni`: [SSE-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE3) (“[Prescott](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_4#Prescott) New Instructions”)
- `pclmulqdq`: [Perform a Carry-Less Multiplication of Quadword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLMUL_instruction_set) [instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PCLMULQDQ.html) — accelerator for [GCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode))
- `dtes64`: 64-bit Debug Store
- `monitor`: Monitor/Mwait support ([Intel SSE3 supplements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE3#Intel_instructions))
- `ds_cpl`: CPL Qual. Debug Store
- `vmx`: Hardware virtualization: Intel [VMX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Intel_virtualization_.28VT-x.29)
- `smx`: Safer mode: [TXT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Execution_Technology) ([TPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) support)
- `est`: Enhanced [SpeedStep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpeedStep)
- `tm2`: [Thermal Monitor 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tm2)
- `ssse3`: [Supplemental SSE-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSSE3)
- `cid`: Context ID
- `sdbg`: silicon debug
- `fma`: [Fused multiply-add](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FMA_instruction_set)
- `cx16`: [CMPXCHG16B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_compare-and-swap)
- `xtpr`: Send Task Priority Messages
- `pdcm`: Performance Capabilities
- `pcid`: Process Context Identifiers
- `dca`: Direct Cache Access
- `sse4_1`: [SSE-4.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4.1#SSE4.1)
- `sse4_2`: [SSE-4.2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4.2#SSE4.2)
- `x2apic`: [x2APIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X2APIC)
- `movbe`: [Move Data After Swapping Bytes](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVBE.html) instruction
- `popcnt`: [Return the Count of Number of Bits Set to 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4#POPCNT_and_LZCNT) [instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/POPCNT.html) ([Hamming weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight), i.e. bit count)
- `tsc_deadline_timer`: Tsc deadline timer
- `aes`/`aes-ni`: [Advanced Encryption Standard (New Instructions)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set)
- `xsave`: [Save Processor Extended States](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/XSAVE.html): also provides [XGETBY](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/XGETBV.html),[XRSTOR](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/XRSTOR.html),[XSETBY](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/XSETBV.html)
- `avx`: [Advanced Vector Extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions)
- `f16c`: 16-bit fp conversions ([CVT16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CVT16_instruction_set))
- `rdrand`: [Read Random Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand) from hardware random number generator [instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/RDRAND.html)
- `hypervisor`: Running on a [hypervisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor)

#### VIA/Cyrix/Centaur-defined CPU features, CPUID level 0xC0000001

- `rng`: [Random Number Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation) present (xstore)
- `rng_en`: [Random Number Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation) enabled
- `ace`: on-CPU crypto (xcrypt)
- `ace_en`: on-CPU crypto enabled
- `ace2`: Advanced Cryptography Engine v2
- `ace2_en`: ACE v2 enabled
- `phe`: PadLock Hash Engine
- `phe_en`: PHE enabled
- `pmm`: PadLock Montgomery Multiplier
- `pmm_en`: PMM enabled

#### More extended AMD flags: CPUID level 0x80000001, ecx

- `lahf_lm`: Load AH from Flags (LAHF) and Store AH into Flags (SAHF) in long mode
- `cmp_legacy`: If yes HyperThreading not valid
- `svm`: “Secure virtual machine”: [AMD-V](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#AMD_virtualization_.28AMD-V.29)
- `extapic`: Extended APIC space
- `cr8_legacy`: CR8 in 32-bit mode
- `abm`: [Advanced Bit Manipulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#ABM_.28Advanced_Bit_Manipulation.29)
- `sse4a`: [SSE-4A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4#SSE4a)
- `misalignsse`: indicates if a general-protection exception (#GP) is generated when some legacy SSE instructions operate on unaligned data. Also depends on CR0 and Alignment Checking bit
- `3dnowprefetch`: 3DNow prefetch instructions
- `osvw`: indicates [OS Visible Workaround](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/24593_APM_v21.pdf), which allows the OS to work around processor errata.
- `ibs`: [Instruction Based Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_performance_counter#Instruction_based_sampling)
- `xop`: [extended AVX instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOP_instruction_set)
- `skinit`: SKINIT/STGI instructions
- `wdt`: [Watchdog timer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer)
- `lwp`: [Light Weight Profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming))
- `fma4`: [4 operands MAC instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FMA_instruction_set)
- `tce`: translation cache extension
- `nodeid_msr`: NodeId MSR
- `tbm`: [Trailing Bit Manipulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#TBM_.28Trailing_Bit_Manipulation.29)
- `topoext`: Topology Extensions CPUID leafs
- `perfctr_core`: Core Performance Counter Extensions
- `perfctr_nb`: NB Performance Counter Extensions
- `bpext`: data breakpoint extension
- `ptsc`: performance time-stamp counter
- `perfctr_l2`: L2 Performance Counter Extensions
- `mwaitx`: `MWAIT` extension (`MONITORX`/`MWAITX`)

#### Auxiliary flags: Linux defined - For features scattered in various CPUID levels

- `ring3mwait`: Ring 3 MONITOR/MWAIT
- `cpuid_fault`: Intel CPUID faulting
- `cpb`: AMD Core Performance Boost
- `epb`: IA32_ENERGY_PERF_BIAS support
- `cat_l3`: Cache Allocation Technology L3
- `cat_l2`: Cache Allocation Technology L2
- `cdp_l3`: Code and Data Prioritization L3
- `invpcid_single`: effectively `invpcid` and `CR4.PCIDE=1`
- `hw_pstate`: AMD HW-PState
- `proc_feedback`: AMD ProcFeedbackInterface
- `sme`: AMD Secure Memory Encryption
- `pti`: [Kernel Page Table Isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_page-table_isolation) (Kaiser)
- `retpoline`: [Retpoline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48089426) mitigation for [Spectre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_(security_vulnerability)) variant 2 (indirect branches)
- `retpoline_amd`: AMD Retpoline mitigation
- `intel_ppin`: Intel Processor Inventory Number
- `avx512_4vnniw`: AVX-512 Neural Network Instructions
- `avx512_4fmaps`: AVX-512 Multiply Accumulation Single precision
- `mba`: Memory Bandwidth Allocation
- `rsb_ctxsw`: Fill RSB on context switches

#### Virtualization flags: Linux defined

- `tpr_shadow`: Intel TPR Shadow
- `vnmi`: Intel Virtual NMI
- `flexpriority`: Intel FlexPriority
- `ept`: Intel Extended Page Table
- `vpid`: Intel Virtual Processor ID
- `vmmcall`: prefer `VMMCALL` to `VMCALL`

#### Intel-defined CPU features, CPUID level 0x00000007:0 (ebx)

- `fsgsbase`: {RD/WR}{FS/GS}BASE instructions
- `tsc_adjust`: TSC adjustment MSR
- `bmi1`: 1st group bit manipulation extensions
- `hle`: [Hardware Lock Elision](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/683688)
- `avx2`: [AVX2 instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions#Advanced_Vector_Extensions_2)
- `smep`: Supervisor Mode Execution Protection
- `bmi2`: 2nd group bit manipulation extensions
- `erms`: Enhanced REP MOVSB/STOSB
- `invpcid`: Invalidate Processor Context ID
- `rtm`: Restricted Transactional Memory
- `cqm`: Cache QoS Monitoring
- `mpx`: Memory Protection Extension
- `rdt_a`: Resource Director Technology Allocation
- `avx512f`: [AVX-512 foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#New_instructions_in_AVX-512_foundation)
- `avx512dq`: [AVX-512 Double/Quad instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#New_instructions_in_AVX-512_BW_and_DQ)
- `rdseed`: The RDSEED instruction
- `adx`: The ADCX and ADOX instructions
- `smap`: Supervisor Mode Access Prevention
- `avx512ifma`: [AVX-512 Integer Fused Multiply Add instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#New_instructions_in_AVX-512_BW_and_DQ)
- `clflushopt`: `CLFLUSHOPT` instruction
- `clwb`: `CLWB` instruction
- `intel_pt`: [Intel Processor Tracing](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/09/18/processor-tracing)
- `avx512pf`: [AVX-512 Prefetch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#New_instructions_in_AVX-512_prefetch)
- `avx512er`: [AVX-512 Exponential and Reciprocal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#New_instructions_in_AVX-512_exponential_and_reciprocal)
- `avx512cd`: [AVX-512 Conflict Detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#New_instructions_in_AVX-512_conflict_detection)
- `sha_ni`: [SHA1/SHA256 Instruction Extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_SHA_extensions)
- `avx512bw`: [AVX-512 Byte/Word instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#New_instructions_in_AVX-512_BW_and_DQ)
- `avx512vl`: AVX-512 128/256 Vector Length extensions

#### Extended state features, CPUID level 0x0000000d:1 (eax)

- `xsaveopt`: Optimized `XSAVE`
- `xsavec`: `XSAVEC`
- `xgetbv1`: `XGETBV` with ECX = 1
- `xsaves`: `XSAVES`/`XRSTORS`

#### Intel-defined CPU QoS sub-leaf, CPUID level 0x0000000F:0 (edx)

- `cqm_llc`: LLC QoS

#### Intel-defined CPU QoS sub-leaf, CPUID level 0x0000000F:1 (edx)

- `cqm_occup_llc`: LLC occupancy monitoring
- `cqm_mbm_total`: LLC total MBM monitoring
- `cqm_mbm_local`: LLC local MBM monitoring

#### AMD-defined CPU features, CPUID level 0x80000008 (ebx)

- `clzero`: `CLZERO` instruction
- `irperf`: instructions retired performance counter
- `xsaveerptr`: Always save/restore FP error pointers

#### Thermal and Power Management leaf, CPUID level 0x00000006 (eax)

- `dtherm` (formerly `dts`): digital thermal sensor
- `ida`: Intel Dynamic Acceleration
- `arat`: Always Running APIC Timer
- `pln`: Intel Power Limit Notification
- `pts`: Intel Package Thermal Status
- `hwp`: Intel Hardware P-states
- `hwp_notify`: HWP notification
- `hwp_act_window`: HWP Activity Window
- `hwp_epp`: HWP Energy Performance Preference
- `hwp_pkg_req`: HWP package-level request

#### AMD SVM Feature Identification, CPUID level 0x8000000a (edx)

- `npt`: AMD Nested Page Table support
- `lbrv`: AMD LBR Virtualization support
- `svm_lock`: AMD SVM locking MSR
- `nrip_save`: AMD SVM next_rip save
- `tsc_scale`: AMD TSC scaling support
- `vmcb_clean`: AMD VMCB clean bits support
- `flushbyasid`: AMD flush-by-ASID support
- `decodeassists`: AMD Decode Assists support
- `pausefilter`: AMD filtered pause intercept
- `pfthreshold`: AMD pause filter threshold
- `avic`: Virtual Interrupt Controller
- `vmsave_vmload`: Virtual VMSAVE VMLOAD
- `vgif`: Virtual GIF

#### Intel-defined CPU features, CPUID level 0x00000007:0 (ecx)

- `avx512vbmi`: AVX512 Vector Bit Manipulation instructions
- `umip`: User Mode Instruction Protection
- `pku`: Protection Keys for Userspace
- `ospke`: OS Protection Keys Enable
- `avx512_vbmi2`: Additional AVX512 Vector Bit Manipulation instructions
- `gfni`: Galois Field New Instructions
- `vaes`: Vector AES
- `vpclmulqdq`: Carry-Less Multiplication Double Quadword
- `avx512_vnni`: Vector Neural Network Instructions
- `avx512_bitalg`: VPOPCNT[B,W] and VPSHUF-BITQMB instructions
- `avx512_vpopcntdq`: POPCNT for vectors of DW/QW
- `la57`: 5-level page tables
- `rdpid`: RDPID instruction

#### AMD-defined CPU features, CPUID level 0x80000007 (ebx)

- `overflow_recov`: MCA overflow recovery support
- `succor`: uncorrectable error containment and recovery
- `smca`: Scalable MCA

#### Detected CPU bugs (Linux-defined)

- `f00f`: [Intel F00F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_F00F_bug)
- `fdiv`: [CPU FDIV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug)
- `coma`: [Cyrix 6x86 coma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrix_coma_bug)
- `amd_tlb_mmatch`: `tlb_mmatch` AMD Erratum 383
- `amd_apic_c1e`: `apic_c1e` AMD Erratum 400
- `11ap`: Bad local APIC aka 11AP
- `fxsave_leak`: FXSAVE leaks FOP/FIP/FOP
- `clflush_monitor`: AAI65, CLFLUSH required before MONITOR
- `sysret_ss_attrs`: SYSRET doesn't fix up SS attrs
- `espfix`: "" IRET to 16-bit SS corrupts ESP/RSP high bits
- `null_seg`: Nulling a selector preserves the base
- `swapgs_fence`: SWAPGS without input dep on GS
- `monitor`: IPI required to wake up remote CPU
- `amd_e400`: CPU is among the affected by Erratum 400
- `cpu_meltdown`: CPU is affected by [meltdown attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meltdown_(security_vulnerability)) and needs kernel page table isolation
- `spectre_v1`: CPU is affected by [Spectre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_(security_vulnerability)) variant 1 attack with conditional branches
- `spectre_v2`: CPU is affected by [Spectre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_(security_vulnerability)) variant 2 attack with indirect branches
- `spec_store_bypass`: CPU is affected by the [Speculative Store Bypass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_Store_Bypass) vulnerability (Spectre variant 4).

<sub>P.S.
This listing was derived from `arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeatures.h` in the kernel source. The flags are listed in the same order as the source code. Please help by adding links to descriptions of features when they're missing, by writing a short description of features that have an unexpressive names, and by updating the list for new kernel versions. The current list is from [Linux 4.15](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeatures.h?id=refs/tags/v4.15) plus some later additions.</sub>

Comment: Thanks @Gilles and editors for an informative question & its summarized and detailed answer. Now, to check whatever CPU capabilities, I use the following taken from NixCraft, eg for Intel CPUs: `$ egrep -wo ^flags|vmx|ept|vpid|npt|tpr_shadow|flexpriority|vnmi|lm|aes' /proc/cpuinfo --color | sort -u`. And there's also the CLI/GUI excellent [i-nex](http://sourceforge.net/projects/i-nex/).

Comment: Outstanding collection of explanations & links; thanks to everyone who contributed.

Comment: Where did the bugs data come from? It doesn't appear to be listed in the cpufeatures.h file.

Comment: @Drazisil As far as I remember all the entries are from the indicated version of `cpufeatures.h`. The descriptions are edited to make them more comprehensible and more informative where someone took the effort to do that.

Comment: @Gilles That seems to be the case for all but the bugs. Setting aside that those aren't `features` I don't see them in that file.

Comment: @Drazisil They are present in the file. And I just updated to 4.15 (mostly new Spectre-related entries).

Comment: i noticed that some of features appear to be listed chronologically. like `fpu`, `sse`, `sse2`, `ssse3`, `sse4_1`, `sse4_2`, `popcnt`, `avx`, `avx2`, etc etc. are the flags actually printed chronologically (i.e. in the order each feature was created/developed), yes/no?

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith Not exactly chronologically, but close. Each flag has an internal number and the flags are listed in numerical order. There are several ranges of numbers depending on who assigns the numbers. The numbers are mostly assigned chronologically within each range.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' 

Kernel 5.10.24 reports this for a Ryzen 3700X CPU: `power management: ts ttp tm hwpstate cpb eff_freq_ro [13] [14]` - I wonder what those `13` and `14` mean.

Answer (score 94):

## ARM

On ARM processors, a few features are mentioned in the `features:` line. Only features directly related to the ARM architecture are mentioned there, not features specific to a silicon manufacturer or system-on-chip.

The features are obtained from looking up the CPU id with [`read_cpuid()`](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/include/asm/cputype.h) and looking it up in the [processor type definitions](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/mm) known at compile time where the features are expressed as a mask of [`HWCAP_xxx`](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/include/uapi/asm/hwcap.h) flags. The corresponding strings are in [`hwcap_str` etc. in `setup.c`](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/kernel/setup.c).

In the list below, ARMv6 introduced SIMD instructions and datatypes. ARMv7 provided Advanced SIMD instructions and datatypes. On 32-bit ARM machines, `neon` signals Advanced SIMD; while `asimd` signals Advanced SIMD on 64-bit arm machines.

- `swp`: [`SWP` instruction](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dht0008a/CJHBGBBJ.html) ([atomic read-modify-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set))
- `half`: [Half-word loads and stores](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/Chdbifed.html)
- `thumb`: [Thumb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Thumb) (16-bit instruction set)
- `26bit`: ["26 Bit" Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/26-bit) (Processor status register folded into program counter)
- `fastmult`: [32×32→64-bit multiplication](http://web.archive.org/web/20160124122604/http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.ports.arm.kernel/4578)
- `fpa`: [Floating point accelerator](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0056d/Bcfhgcgd.html)
- `vfp`: [VFP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Floating-point_.28VFP.29) (early [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) vector floating point instructions)
- `edsp`: [DSP extensions](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/technologies/dsp-simd.php) (the 'e' variant of the ARM9 CPUs, and all others above)
- `java`: [Jazelle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazelle) (Java bytecode accelerator)
- `iwmmxt`: [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) instructions [similar to Intel MMX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMX_%28instruction_set%29#MMX_in_embedded_applications)
- `crunch`: [MaverickCrunch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MaverickCrunch) coprocessor (if kernel support enabled)
- `thumbee`: [ThumbEE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Thumb_Execution_Environment_.28ThumbEE.29)
- `neon`: [Advanced SIMD/NEON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Advanced_SIMD_.28NEON.29) (`asimd` on AArch64 older kernels)
- `vfpv3`: VFP version 3
- `vfpv3d16`: [VFP version 3 with 16 D-registers](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dht0002a/ch01s03s02.html)
- `tls`: [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) register
- `vfpv4`: VFP version 4 with fast context switching
- `idiva`: `SDIV` and `UDIV` hardware division in ARM mode
- `idivt`: `SDIV` and `UDIV` hardware division in Thumb mode
- `vfpd32`: [VFP with 32 D-registers](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dht0002a/ch01s03s02.html)
- `lpae`: [Large Physical Address Extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Large_Physical_Address_Extension_.28LPAE.29) (>4GB physical memory on 32-bit architecture)
- `evtstrm`: kernel event stream using generic architected timer
- `aes`: hardware-accelerated [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) (secret-key cryptography)
- `pmull{2}`: [64×64→128-bit F<sub>2<sup>m</sup></sub> multiplication](http://conradoplg.cryptoland.net/files/2010/12/gcm14.pdf) — acceleration for the GCM mode of authenticated encryption
- `sha1`: hardware-accelerated [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1)
- `sha2`: hardware-accelerated [SHA-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2)
- `sha512`: hardware-accelerated [SHA-512](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2)
- `sha3`: hardware-accelerated [SHA-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3)
- `sm3`: hardware-accelerated [SM3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SM3_(hash_function))
- `sm4`: hardware-accelerated [SM4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SM4_(cipher))
- `crc32`: hardware-accelerated [CRC-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#CRC-32_algorithm)

Beyond that, the `Hardware:` line indicates the processor model. Depending on the model, there may be other information in other files under `/proc` or `/sys`, or in boot-time kernel log messages. Unfortunately each ARM CPU manufacturer has its own method for reporting processor features, if any.

Comment: https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/arm/armv8

Comment: @Zboson, thanks for the link. I saw `fp` on rpi zero 2 w, from the link it means single and double floats support.

Answer (score 12):

### x86

**Find it yourself in 4.1.3 x86 and the Intel manual**

[`arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h?id=refs/tags/v4.1.3) contains the full list.

The define values are of type:

```
X*32 + Y
```

E.g.:

```
#define X86_FEATURE_FPU     ( 0*32+ 0) /* Onboard FPU */
```

The features flags, extracted from CPUID, are stored inside the:

- `__u32 x86_capability[NCAPINTS + NBUGINTS];` field
- of `struct cpuinfo_x86 boot_cpu_data`
- defined at `x86/kernel/setup.c`

which is initialized through `__init` functions.

Where each `x86_capability` array element comes from:

```
| index | eax      | ecx | output | file        |
|-------|----------|-----|--------|-------------|
|     0 |        1 |   0 | edx    | common.c    |
|     1 | 80000001 |     | edx    | common.c    |
|     2 | 80860001 |     | edx    | transmeta.c |
|     3 |          |     |        |             |
|     4 |        1 |   0 | ecx    | common.c    |
|     5 | C0000001 |     | edx    | centaur.c   |
|     6 | 80000001 |     | ecx    | common.c    |
|     7 |          |     |        | scattered.c |
|     8 |          |     |        |             |
|     9 |        7 |   0 | ebx    | common.c    |
|    10 |        D |   1 | eax    | common.c    |
|    11 |        F |   0 | edx    | common.c    |
|    12 |        F |   1 | edx    | common.c    |
```

Notes:

- empty entries mean: "from various places" or "not available"
- `index`: is the index of `x86_capability`, e.g. `x86_capability[0]`
- `eax` and `exc`: are the input values for CPUID in hex. Inputs that use `exc`, which are fewer, call it the *subleaf* (of a 2 level tree with `eax` at the root).
- `output`: is the register from which CPUID output is taken
- `file`: is the file where those fields are defined. Paths are relative to `arch/x86/kernel/cpu/`.
- `transmeta`: was the name of a CPU vendor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmeta that was acquired by Novafora https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/novafora
- `centaur`: was the name of a CPU vendor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centaur_Technology that was acquired by VIA https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VIA_Technologies. Cyrix is another one.

Conclusions:

- most entries come directly from CPUID output registers and are set in `common.c` by something like:

  ```
  c->x86_capability[0] = edx;
  ```

  Those are easy to find in batch on the Intel manual for CPUID.
- the others are scattered throughout the source, and are set bit by bit with `set_cpu_cap`.

  To find them, use `git grep X86_FEATURE_XXX` inside `arch/x86`.

  You can usually deduce what CPUID bit they correspond to from the surrounding code.

**Other fun facts**

- The flags are actually printed at `arch/x86/kernel/cpu/proc.c` with the code:

  ```
  seq_puts(m, "flags\t\t:");
  for (i = 0; i < 32*NCAPINTS; i++)
      if (cpu_has(c, i) && x86_cap_flags[i] != NULL)
          seq_printf(m, " %s", x86_cap_flags[i]);
  ```

  Where:

  - `cpu_has` does the main check for the feature.
  - `x86_cap_flags[i]` contains strings that correspond to each flags.

  This gets passed as a callback to the `proc` system setup. The entry point is at `fs/proc/cpuinfo.c`.
- `x86_cap_flags` strings are generated by `arch/x86/kernel/cpu/mkcapflags.h` directly from `arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h` by "parsing" it with `sed`...

  The output goes to `arch/x86/kernel/cpu/capflags.c` of the build directory, and resulting array looks like:

  ```
  const char * const x86_cap_flags[NCAPINTS*32] = {
      [X86_FEATURE_FPU]        = "fpu",
      [X86_FEATURE_VME]        = "vme",
  ```

  so for example `X86_FEATURE_FPU` corresponds to the string `"fpu"` and so on.
- `cpu_has` breaks down into two cases with code:

  ```
  #define cpu_has(c, bit)                         \
      (__builtin_constant_p(bit) && REQUIRED_MASK_BIT_SET(bit) ? 1 :  \
      test_cpu_cap(c, bit))
  ```

  They are:

  - `__builtin_constant_p(bit) && REQUIRED_MASK_BIT_SET(bit)`: the flag is required for the kernel to run.

    This is determined by data inside `required-features.h`, which comments:

    ```
    Define minimum CPUID feature set for kernel These bits are checked
    really early to actually display a visible error message before the
    kernel dies.  Make sure to assign features to the proper mask!
    ```

    Since those are known at compile time (kernel requirements), have already been checked at startup, the check can be resolved at compile time if `bit` is known at compile time.

    Thus the `__builtin_constant_p(bit)` which checks if `bit` is a compile time constant.
  - `test_cpu_cap`: this uses up `CPUID` data from the `struct cpuinfo_x86 boot_cpu_data` global

Comment: You've explained how to go from the abbreviation to a longer name, but often that longer name isn't much more comprehensible, and `cpuid` does it in a more convenient way. I asked that question to have a place where the names are documented.

Comment: @Gilles this is mostly for those who want to make the tables / cannot find their feature in the table, like me :-) But still, for most cases, once you look at the right point of the source, the map to CPUID is immediate.

Answer (score 10):

Or alternatively you can use `cpuid` program, it must be in debian repository. It dumps every possible info about your CPU with some explanations, so you don't get those obscure flags.

Comment: `cpuid` expands the abbreviations. I wouldn't really call its output *explanations*. Knowing that `ht` means “Hyper Threading” explains it to some extent, but knowing that `mmx` means “MMX instruction set”, not so much, and that `mca` means “Machine Check Architecture”, hardly.

Comment: @Gilles ...and yet, "Machine Check Architecture" is certainly better Google query than "mca" ;)

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by the top answer by @Gilles, here is a bash script (requires bash v4 or higher, a network connection, and a recent wget) to annotate the current CPU flags:

```bash
#! /bin/bash

CPUFEATURES="$(wget -qO- "https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/plain/arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeatures.h")" 
grep "^flags" /proc/cpuinfo |
        uniq |
        sed 's/^.*: //' |
        tr ' ' '\n' |
        while read line; do
                echo -n "${line}: "
                echo "$CPUFEATURES" |
                grep "FEATURE_${line^^}" |
                        sed 's|.*) /\* ||' |
                        sed 's| \*/$||'
        done
```

Comment: Great link there, but the script doesn't appear to work for me. It either hangs infinitely or exits with nothing (Ubuntu 20.10).

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs Fixed.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Better, but now it only outputs the CPU flags all on 1 line without any annotations.

Comment: same in my case, just a line of flags printed out

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs fixed

Answer (score 2):

Top answer is best "The full listing is in the kernel source, in the file [arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeatures.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeatures.h)." Use that and internet/processor manuals to understand meaning of each flag.

Adding an answer to compliment the existing answers with a specific example from HP Proliant G8 Intel Xeon server to show the lscpu output and compare lscpu/flags from this machine as a VM host and VM running on it. Openstack qemu-kvm is the virtualisation server running here.

- CPU(s): 24 vs 22

  2 CPUs pinned for openstack controller on VM host.
   24 CPUs in total. In VM can see 22 CPUs available.
- Threads/Cores/Sockets/NUMA show different. (see below)
- Model, Model name, Stepping, CPU MHz, L2 cache size show as different. (see  more below)

  on host: Model: 45
  Model name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2640 0 @ 2.50GHz

  on VM: Model:                 42
  Model name:            Intel Xeon E312xx (Sandy Bridge, IBRS update)
- FLAGS

  - extra 2 flags on VM:

    - hypervisor: Running on a hypervisor
    - tsc_adjust: TSC adjustment MSR
      TSC = Timestamp Counter (an Intel register) https://wiki.osdev.org/TSC
      MSR = Model Specific Register https://wiki.osdev.org/MSR
  - missing 31 flags on VM:

    - dts:  Debug Store (buffer for debugging and profiling instructions)
    - acpi: ACPI via MSR (temperature monitoring and clock speed modulation)
      https://wiki.osdev.org/ACPI
      ACPI (Advanced Configuration and Power Interface) is a Power Management and configuration standard for the PC
    - ht: Hyper-Threading and/or multi-core
    - tm: Automatic clock control (Thermal Monitor)
    - pbe: Pending Break Enable (PBE# pin) wakeup support
    - arch_perfmon: Intel Architectural PerfMon
    - pebs: Precise-Event Based Sampling
    - bts: Branch Trace Store
    - nonstop_tsc: TSC does not stop in C states
      TSC = Timestamp Counter (an Intel register) https://wiki.osdev.org/TSC
    - aperfmperf: APERF and MPERF are MSR registers
      "APERF and MPERF are MSR registers that can provide feedback on
      current CPU frequency."
    - dtes64: 64-bit Debug Store
    - monitor: Monitor/Mwait support (Intel SSE3 supplements)
    - ds_cpl: CPL Qual. Debug Store - CPL is the current privilege level (bits in CS register)
    - vmx: Hardware virtualization: Intel VMX
    - smx: Safer mode: TXT(Trusted Execution Technology) (TPM(Trusted Platform Module) support)
    - est: Enhanced SpeedStep
    - tm2: Thermal Monitor 2
    - xtpr: Send Task Priority Messages
    - pdcm: Performance Capabilities
    - dca: Direct Cache Access
    - epb: IA32_ENERGY_PERF_BIAS support
    - tpr_shadow: Intel TPR Shadow
      TPR = Task Priority Register
    - vnmi: Intel Virtual NMI
      https://wiki.osdev.org/NMI (Non Maskable Interrupt)
    - flexpriority: Intel FlexPriority
      Intel Virtualisation Technology
    - ept: Intel Extended Page Table
    - vpid: Intel Virtual Processor ID
    - dtherm: (formerly dts) digital thermal sensor
    - ida: Intel Dynamic Acceleration
    - pln: Intel Power Limit Notification
    - pts: Intel Package Thermal Status
    - flush_l1d: Flush L1(level 1)D(data) cache

lscpu full output:

```
[root@host ~]# lscpu
Architecture: x86_64
CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order: Little Endian
CPU(s): 24
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-23
Thread(s) per core: 2
Core(s) per socket: 6
Socket(s): 2
NUMA node(s): 2
Vendor ID: GenuineIntel
CPU family: 6
Model: 45
Model name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2640 0 @ 2.50GHz
Stepping: 7
CPU MHz: 2375.000
CPU max MHz: 2500.0000
CPU min MHz: 1200.0000
BogoMIPS: 4987.53
Virtualization: VT-x
L1d cache: 32K
L1i cache: 32K
L2 cache: 256K
L3 cache: 15360K
NUMA node0 CPU(s): 0-5,12-17
NUMA node1 CPU(s): 6-11,18-23
Flags: fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm epb ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts spec_ctrl intel_stibp flush_l1d    openstack compute-node VM

[root@VM ~]$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                22 
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-21
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             22
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 42
Model name:            Intel Xeon E312xx (Sandy Bridge, IBRS update)
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               2493.748
BogoMIPS:              4987.49
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              4096K
L3 cache:              16384K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-21
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tsc_adjust xsaveopt arat spec_ctrl intel_stibp
```