# How do I find out if my computer has PAE using Linux?

Tags: centos, system-installation, system-information, pae

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the flags in /proc/cpuinfo mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43539/what-do-the-flags-in-proc-cpuinfo-mean)

I tried installing CentOS 6.3 on my computer only to see a complaint that my computer doesn't have PAE. I am not sure if my computer has it and it's just disabled or if it doesn't have PAE at all.

I am using Mageia 2 right now and I want to check if I can turn it on (in case it's off) or if my computer doesn't have it.

My current computer is an IBM ThinkPad X32. I know it's kind of old but this (CentOS 6.3) is the first ever Linux distro to give me that error of not having PAE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you examine the contents of `/proc/cpuinfo`, the flags for the CPU will include "pae".

Comment: quite obvious but for the beginner: `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep pae`

Answer (score 2):

pae will be in the "flags" section of the output of 'cat /proc/cpuinfo'

PAE is Physical Address Extension. It's a way of addressing large amounts of memory.

Here are a couple of links about it:
https://serverfault.com/questions/85980/what-processors-do-do-not-support-pae

http://pacoup.com/2009/05/27/pae-vs-64-bit-what-manufacturers-dont-want-you-to-know/comment-page-1/