# CPU MSR dumper tool

Tags: linux, cpu, x86

I'm looking for a linux tool similar to a cpuid dumper but with a capability to read all of a processor's possible [model-specific registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-specific_register)'s and outputting them.  Does such a tool exist?  I'm hoping to get the dump so I can parse the dump to look for whatever CPU features I'd be interested in.  Please let me know if I'm asking in the wrong forum.

Comment: What's MSR in this context?

Comment: Model specific register:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-specific_register . Hope this is what you mean.

Comment: Do you want to dump all the MSR contents or to list CPU features? Those are different questions. You can find a [list of CPU features in `/proc/cpuinfo`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43539/what-do-the-flags-in-proc-cpuinfo-mean?s=14|0.7258), but I don't know how much that tells you about MSR contents (it should at least tell you which MSR are available).

Comment: I want to dump all MSR contents.  Something similar to dumping cpuid. ie: