# Detect if the computers hardware is capable for a 64bit system?

Tags: linux, command-line, hardware, 64bit, 32bit

I'm more and more getting into trouble with my `Debian 32 bit system`, since some software such as the [signal messenger](https://signal.org) are not written for `32 bit` anymore.

```
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid
          Kernel: Linux 5.8.0-2-686-pae
    Architecture: x86
```

I am not sure if this `32 bit system` was installed rather by mistake, then of the hardware capability. **Is there a way to detect whether my hardware is capable of running on `64 bit` or not?** *(prefarably from the command-line)*

Comment: Did you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/246007?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run these commands, if `x86_64` and `64-bit`, the answer would be yes:

```
$ lscpu | grep Arch
Architecture:                    x86_64


$ lscpu | grep mode
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
```

From [32-bit, 64-bit CPU op-mode on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77718/32-bit-64-bit-cpu-op-mode-on-linux)

> `lscpu` is telling you that your architecture is i686 (an Intel 32-bit CPU), and that your CPU supports both 32-bit and 64-bit operating modes. You won't be able to install x64 built applications since they're built specifically for x64 architectures. Your particular CPU can handle either the i386 or i686 built packages.

---

Here's a list of the flags of `/proc/cpuinfo`:

[What do the flags in /proc/cpuinfo mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43540/338177)

Comment: Yes, I get `Architecture: i686` and `CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit`

Comment: @nath This https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/77718 describes exactly your scenario

Comment: Look at my edited answer

Comment: @Quasímodo if I run `cat /proc/cpuinfo` I get: `clflush size: 64; cache_alignment: 64; address sizes: 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual` for both CPUs.