# How to know if a AMD cpu's SME feature is enabled?

Tags: memory, encryption, cpu, amd

More recent AMD CPUs have a feature named [Secure Memory Encryption SME](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/x86/amd-memory-encryption.html) which if available can be explicitly be enabled by adding this parameter to linux' command line.

```
mem_encrypt=on
```

(according to https://libvirt.org/kbase/launch_security_sev.html)

I am unsure if my system (with an AMD EPYC cpu) has this feature enabled (i.e. if the feature might be default on anyway).

My question is how to check if the AMD SME feature is enabled?

Since https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/x86/amd-memory-encryption.html suggests that:

> If support for SME is present, MSR 0xc00100010 (MSR_K8_SYSCFG) can be
> used to determine if SME is enabled and/or to enable memory
> encryption:

I have run this commands (on a debian 10):

```
apt-get install msr-tools
rdmsr --raw 0xc0010010  | xxd -b
```

which presented me this output

```
00000000: 00000000 00000000 11110100 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
00000006: 00000000 00000000
```

where according to the source quoted the 23rd bit indicates if SME is indeed enabled/active (=1) or not (=0).

If above is indeed the correct way to test this, a confirmation may be considered a valid answer, ideally of course providing some background.
Else again I would be very happy to be able to check the state of SME on a running linux system.

Comment: You could check `/proc/cpuinfo` - according to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43539/what-do-the-flags-in-proc-cpuinfo-mean), there should be a flag for SME

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If SME is supported (`CPUID` shows the corresponding bit set) *and* enabled (the appropriate MSR bit is set), `/proc/cpuinfo` will contain the `sme` flag. You can verify this by [looking at the kernel code which detects SME](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.4/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/amd.c#L605): the SME feature, which is reflected directly in `/proc/cpuinfo`, is cleared if SME isn’t fully enabled.

You should also see [corresponding messages in the kernel boot logs](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.4/source/arch/x86/mm/mem_encrypt.c#L411):

> AMD Memory Encryption Features active: SME

if SME is active,

> AMD Memory Encryption Features active: SEV SEV-ES

if SEV and/or SEV-ES are active.

See also [What do the flags in /proc/cpuinfo mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43539/86440)

Comment: Thanks for linking to a source code. Odly on the debian10 4.19.0-13-amd64 kernel kernel logs displayed via `dmesg` do not repo the output about SME enabled. Yet *odly* `grep sme /proc/cpuinfo` shows up. Did I understand your answer incorrectly or should both not concur? A

Comment: In 4.19, the messages were different; you should see “AMD Secure Memory Encryption (SME) active”.

Comment: I did `dmesg | grep -i sme | wc -l` for not being certain about upper/lowercase `sme`/`Sme`/`SME` if the kernel log output would be 100% exactly the same. Yet still the result `0` leaves me a little puzzled. Thanks for responding :)

Comment: Does your `dmesg` output still contain the early boot messages?

Comment: `dmesg  | head -n 2` yields this
`[    0.000000] Linux version 4.19.0-13-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)) #1 SMP Debian 4.19.160-2 (2020-11-28)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.19.0-13-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/vg-root ro mem_encrypt=on
`. I will attempt to find out how early that is. I was not aware that dmesg might have different levels of earlyness. thanks for the hint

Comment: That’s the very first log message, so early enough ;-). The issue with `dmesg` is that it shows the kernel log, which is a circular buffer — so on systems that have been up for a while, or that have lots of kernel logs, the start can be lost.