# How to use a 64-bit CPU in KVM?

Tags: arch-linux, kvm

According to tests the Mac Mini 3,1 [CPU is 64-bit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14384/how-do-i-know-that-my-cpu-supports-64bit-operating-systems-under-linux) (`grep -q "^flags.*\blm\b" /proc/cpuinfo`) and [supports Intel virtualization extensions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95275/unable-to-install-64-bit-vm-using-kvm) (`grep -q "^flags.*\bvmx\b" /proc/cpuinfo`). However, after running `kvm -m 512 -boot d -cdrom archlinux-2012.07.15-netinstall-dual.iso` and looking in the Hardware Detection Tool, the processor is listed as *not* x86_64. Using `-cpu kvm64` doesn't help. Is it also necessary to have a 64-bit kernel (I don't)?

Comment: Have a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43539/what-do-the-flags-in-proc-cpuinfo-mean - `svm` is the flag for AMD not Intel, i highly doubt your system has a `svm` flag (but this is probably unrelated to your problem)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell but seems like it, you need an x86_64 kernel on the host in order to run a 64bit guest.

Looking at KVM FAQ, we could read:

> Can KVM run a 32-bit guest on a 64-bit host? What about PAE?
>
> KVM supports 32-bit guests on 64-bit hosts, and any combination of
>   PAE and non-PAE guests and hosts. **The only unsupported
>   combination is a 64-bit guest  on a 32-bit host.**

Virtualizing a 64bits guest on a 32bits host, would be more like an "emulation" because there would be instructions from your guest, your host won't understand. They're both different architectures but I guess we can virtualize 32 bits guest on a 64 bits host cause both architectures share a common base...

Comment: It's too bad that they talk about "host", since it's not at all clear whether they mean the CPU or the kernel. Ah well.

Comment: @l0b0 On Linux, you need a 64-bit kernel to run anything 64-bit. VirtualBox however can run a 64-bit guest on a 32-bit host kernel as long as your CPU has virtualization extensions (vmx/svm).

Comment: And the performance is correspondingly horrible. It's best to use a 64-bit host if you intend to virtualize 64-bit guests.

Comment: After seeing @Gilles answer I went to VirtualBox documentation and they say there's overhead in such an environment so I guess they do some sort of translation/emulation that is making it to have bad performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use qemu command line argument to assign special virtual cpu.
There are some type 32bit cpu.

-cpu model

## Select CPU model (-cpu ? for list and additional feature selection)

qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu ?
x86           qemu64  QEMU Virtual CPU version 1.4.2
x86           phenom  AMD Phenom(tm) 9550 Quad-Core Processor
x86         core2duo  Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T7700  @ 2.40GHz 
x86            kvm64  Common KVM processor
x86           qemu32  QEMU Virtual CPU version 1.4.2
x86            kvm32  Common 32-bit KVM processor
x86          coreduo  Genuine Intel(R) CPU           T2600  @ 2.16GHz 
x86              486
x86          pentium
x86         pentium2
x86         pentium3
x86           athlon  QEMU Virtual CPU version 1.4.2
x86             n270  Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N270   @ 1.60GHz
x86           Conroe  Intel Celeron_4x0 (Conroe/Merom Class Core 2)
x86           Penryn  Intel Core 2 Duo P9xxx (Penryn Class Core 2)
x86          Nehalem  Intel Core i7 9xx (Nehalem Class Core i7)
x86         Westmere  Westmere E56xx/L56xx/X56xx (Nehalem-C)
x86      SandyBridge  Intel Xeon E312xx (Sandy Bridge)
x86          Haswell  Intel Core Processor (Haswell)
x86       Opteron_G1  AMD Opteron 240 (Gen 1 Class Opteron)
x86       Opteron_G2  AMD Opteron 22xx (Gen 2 Class Opteron)
x86       Opteron_G3  AMD Opteron 23xx (Gen 3 Class Opteron)
x86       Opteron_G4  AMD Opteron 62xx class CPU
x86       Opteron_G5  AMD Opteron 63xx class CPU